# Agora.io Record Audio from LiveStream

Tags: react-native, file, audio, agora.io

I try to make a group Audio recorder with Agora.io, so I first need to create an empty .aac audio file so that I can record the audio on this File.
I use the react-native-fetch-blob library to handle the File System.

Here is my code for Recording:

```
const handleAudio = async () => {
    const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
    const dirs = fs.dirs;
    if (!startAudio) {
      fs.createFile(dirs.DocumentDir + '/record.aac', 'foo', 'utf8').then(() => {
        _engine?.startAudioRecording(
          dirs.DocumentDir + '/record.aac',
          AudioSampleRateType.Type44100,
          AudioRecordingQuality.Medium,
        );
        setStartAudio(true);
      });
    } else {
      _engine?.stopAudioRecording();
    }
  };
```

The problem is that the file 'record.aac' always stays the same and the Agora.io recorder does not update this new file, it remains with 'foo'...

Comment: Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [`startAudioRecording`](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/react_native/classes/rtcengine.html#startaudiorecording) function expect a directory instead of a file.

Example: `/sdcard/emulated/0/audio/aac`.

It also returns a promise that you can check for the result.

Comment: Thank you very much :) But when I try it doesn't work...

Comment: Do you get an error in the promise result?